# extjs - How to set Ext.Img's data by a part of response?

Tags: javascript, image, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

`Ext.Img` [provides a method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Img-method-setSrc) named `setSrc` to set URL of an image. In order to prevent another call to the server when the image is a part of `form` data, I need to set the image through the response data.

Comment: You would have to look into the topic of "Data URLs". You can use `setSrc` with a data URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alexander suggested, you can call `setSrc` with a data URL. When the server request returned the image data encoded as base64 you can add it to the image without a server request.

```
// An empty image added to the HTML body
var img = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'img',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 64,
    width: 64
});

// later when you fetched the data you can add it to the image
var imgBase64EncodedData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...';
img.setSrc(imgBase64EncodedData);
```

See [Data URIs - Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and the [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23qd).